# how to change the carrier name in my iphone 6 without Jailbreak?

Tags: ios, iphone

how to change the carrier name in my iphone 6 without Jailbreak? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to change the displayed name of your carrier, I'm afraid you can't do that without a jailbreak.